# Assembly built using ver. 1.1, still looking for 1.0 at runtime

Tags: c#, dll, assemblies, versioning

I have two assemblies that I have built, assembly `A` references assembly `B`. Both work fine when they are both version 1.0.

But whenever I want to update the assemblies, I increment assembly `B` to 1.1 and build the DLL. Then I change project/assembly `A` to reference the 1.1 version of assembly `B`. Everything builds just fine. But when I go to run my application that invokes assembly `A` (which in turn invokes assembly `B`) I am getting a runtime error saying that version 1.0 of assembly `B` cannot be found.

I hope I've made myself clear enough, It's not so easy to explain...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well, something *somewhere* wants 1.0; your best bet is to trawl back through trying to find what is still referencing 1.0, and *fix that*. However, if you are happy that the API is forwards compatible, you can also fix this in configuration, via a `<bindingRedirect>` from `1.0.0.0` to `1.1.0.0` (or whatever the version is). See MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eftw1fys(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Nothing seems to be looking at that version `1.0.0.0` anywhere. I am probably missing something, like a wrong version sitting in a bin directory somewhere that is being referenced at build or something odd.